# How to create proper asynchronous validators in Angular?

Tags: angular, validation, asynchronous

I'm trying to create a simple asynchronous validators in Angular to make sure that a username is not duplicated:

THE VALIDATOR CLASS:

```
import { AbstractControl, ValidationErrors } from "@angular/forms";

export class UsernameValidators {
    static shouldBeUnique(control: AbstractControl): Promise<ValidationErrors | null> {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                if (control.value === 'Robert') {
                    resolve({ shouldBeUnique: true });
                } else {
                    resolve(null);
                }
            }, 2000);
        });
    }
}
```

SIGN UP FORM.TS

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { UsernameValidators } from './username.validators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-signup-form',
  templateUrl: './signup-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./signup-form.component.css']
})
export class SignupFormComponent {

  form = new FormGroup({
    username: new FormControl('', UsernameValidators.shouldBeUnique)
  });

  get getUsername() {
    return this.form.get('username');
  }

}
```

SIGN UP FORM.HTML

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="userLabel">
            Username
        </label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="Username" formControlName="username">
        <div *ngIf="getUsername?.['touched'] && getUsername?.['invalid']" class="alert alert-danger">
            <div *ngIf="getUsername?.errors?.['shouldBeUnique']">Username is already taken.</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

I want it so that if a user enters 'Robert' in the input element, it should display an error message saying 'Username is already taken.' However, it does it this instead:

[image]

In fact, it does that to every input:

[image]

Is there anything wrong I am doing with the Angular asynchronous validator? If so, I'd like to learn what it is. Thanks!

Comment: The first argument is the value, the second the sync validators en the third the async validators so: username: new FormControl('', [],  [UsernameValidators.shouldBeUnique])

Comment: @MikeOne That worked! Thank you. But I thought that the second argument is an option between an array of validators or one validator? Maybe I should check the Angular website for more clarification